# How do I use collection_select syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a Department model, Course model and Mandatory model.
Each department has some courses that are mandatory, so I use the Mandatory model to map between Courses and Department model.

I want to be able to create the 'mandatory' relationship by selecting the names of course and departments instead of their id.

I figured I would create 2 instance variables @departments(Department.all) and @courses(Course.all) and in the view I would show them as drop down so you choose 1 department, 1 course and create the Mandatory relationship. Turns out it's not as simple as I would have liked it to be. I do not understand how am I supposed to use the `collection_select` helper method. I have read the documentation and I don't understand it.

So my Department Model is

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :industry_name, :name

has_many :employees
has_many :mandatories
has_many :courses, :through => :mandatories
end
```

Course Model

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name

has_many :registrations
has_many :mandatories
has_many :employees, :through => :registrations
has_many :departments, :through => :mandatories
end
```

Mandatory Model

```
class Mandatory < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :course_id, :department_id

belongs_to :course
belongs_to :department
end
```

The syntax I got from the documentation is `<%= collection_select(:person, :city_id, City.all, :id, :name) %>`

Do not understand this at all.

EDIT::

So, heres is my current view. I have no `collection_select` yet. right now to create a relationship between a Department and a Course I need to enter their ids which I don't want to do. I would like a drop down with department name and course name instead.

This is my `_form.html` for Mandatory Controller

```
<%= form_for(@mandatory) do |f| %>
<% if @mandatory.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@mandatory.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this mandatory from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @mandatory.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :department_id %><br />
  <%= f.number_field :department_id %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :course_id %><br />
  <%= f.number_field :course_id %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And here is Mandatory Controller

```
def create
@mandatory = Mandatory.new(params[:mandatory])
@courses = Course.all
@departments  =Department.all
respond_to do |format|
  if @mandatory.save
    format.html { redirect_to @mandatory, notice: 'Mandatory was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @mandatory, status: :created, location: @mandatory }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @mandatory.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use it in the context of a form like so:

```
<% form_for @mandatory do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :course_id %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select(:course_id, Course.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: the City syntax is just a syntax from the documentation. It has nothing to do with my view.

Comment: @ChalamphongPandey I have updated to be more specific to your case

Comment: so here `:course_id` is the column in which the selection value will go, `Course.all` is an array of all the options, `:id` is the value of each option and `:name` is the text displayed in the drop down menu. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= collection_select(:person, :city_id, City.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Let's look at the parts:

`:person` is the name of the model that contains one item from the collection.

`:city_id` is the name of the field in the model that contains the item from the collection.

`City.all` is the list of items in the collection. This could be an instance variable (`@cities`) if you did the database request in the controller (`@cities = City.all`). You can also fetch just a subset of the records if that is all you need in the collection (`@cities = City.where("state = ?", ["NY", "SC", "NE"])`)

`:id` and `:name` are the fields in the `City` object that are used in each line if the selection list. `:id` is the value and `:name` is the text for each option in the dropdown list.

The HTML generated should look like

```
<select name="person[city_id]">
<option value="1">New York</option>
<option value="3">Rome</option>
<option value="4">Charleston</option>
<option value="17">Omaha</option>
</select>
```

EDIT: the 'id' in select seems to have dropped out when I wasn't looking, so I have removed it.

Comment: Well, darn it, now I'm not sure if the id attribute appears in HTML select or not. The API reference doesn't show it, but I remember it being there from projects past. The perils of doing this from memory...

Comment: Thank you for your response, I did'nt get it at first but I had to read it many times to get this. Thank you for your help. And I got it working and the `:id` attribute does show up in the HTML. In the above case it would be like `<select id="person_city_id" name="person[city_id]">`

Comment: Are you using Rails 4 or Rails 3?